# how to add values of two arrays with common index in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Consider the following arrays:

Array 1 with contents:

```
index1    value2
a         5
b         6
c         2
```

And Array 2 with contents:

```
index2   value2
a         4
b         2
```

i need an Array 3 which should be the sum of the above 2 arrays.
Something like:

```
index     value
a           9
b           8
c           2
```

Comment: Please format your question in correct way to get answer

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: i have formatted, please review the question..

Answer (score 1):

This function will be what you need:

```
function array_merge_with_sum_values(array $array1, array $array2){
        $finalArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
        $keys = array_keys($finalArray);
        foreach($keys as $key){
            if(isset($array1[$key]) && isset($array2[$key])){
                $finalArray[$key] = $array1[$key] + $array2[$key];
            }
        }
        return $finalArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you:

```
$array_first = ['a'=>5,'b'=>6,'c'=>2];
$array_second = ['a'=>4,'b'=>2];
function sum_array($array_first,$array_second){
$array_result = [];
foreach ($array_first as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($array_second[$key])){
        $array_result[$key] = $array_second[$key] + $array_first[$key];
    }else{
        $array_result[$key] = $array_first[$key];
    }
}
return $array_result;}
var_dump(sum_array($array_first,$array_second));
```

**Result :**

```
 array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(9)
  ["b"]=>
  int(8)
  ["c"]=>
  int(2)
}
```